# Hide UIPicker after Selection

Tags: ios, swift, picker, uipicker

I have a UIPicker and I want to save selection and hide it after selection. I  can't find a way to do this. 
Can I do this without a "Save" button? Can I just save the selection pressing on the row?
Currently I press a button to make the picker appear ( picker.isHidden = false), but then it stays after selection has been made.

```
  //Picker

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return fiatArray.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return fiatArray[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    displayConvertedValues(forSelected: row)

}

func displayConvertedValues(forSelected row :Int) {

    let chosenfiat = fiatArray[row]
    getData(fiat: chosenfiat)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to submit you choice, try to implement a mechanism for that, like a toolbar on top of the picker view (like facebook see the screen below). With that mechanism you can save your choice and implement the picker hidden method when you click on the "save button"

[image: Facebook Picker Screen]

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks, what I want is to hide the uipicker after selection. I dont want to put a Done button.

Comment: how will you trigger the selection so ? because each time you pass through a value it will be triggered as a selection I think. Have you seen something you want to implement in another app ?

Comment: After selection, if the user taps again on the value, the uipicker will be closed.  I am thinking how can I detect the tap on the uipicker.. ?

Comment: one way can be adding a transparent view in the center of your picker view and attach a gestureRecognizer to this view but be careful car this view will be on top of the picker view and can potentially disturb the picker view selection if the user start dragging the picker view on this view. That is why I don't personally approve that approach

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think you are right.  Maybe is better to use the traditional approach because that is what users are accustomed to.  I will put a Done button.